# how to parse the web service result as arraycollection?

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, arraycollection, flex-builder-3

I am using Flex Builder and the IDE generates all the calls to my web service. I want to build a filter in a datagrid which it's provider is the result of a web service.

I think I cannot build a filter using the web service response, or if somebody know how to do it I will really appreciate.

In another hand, I have the option to parse the web service response as an arraycollection and then build the filter, does somebody knows how to catch the response and parse it as an arraycollection, keeping in mind that the service has generated by Flex Builder.

Thanks all!

Comment: You're going to have to give us details on what you're getting back from the web service before we can help you process it.  Is it AMF or SOAP or Rest?  Are you receiving an Array or XML or JSON or something different?

Comment: It's Rest and I am receiving a JSON array.